# Video HTML5 on iOS : Autoplay with sound on click only

Tags: ios, html, audio, video, autoplay

I try to integrate a video (MP4) on my site, which automatically starts (autoplay) without the sound, but when you click on the video to see it bigger, you must be able to have the sound.

I can not do it, is it forbidden ?

PS : I read this : https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

With this code bellow, autoplay works but I have no sound on iPad when I click on the video.

```
<video id="video-autoplay" src="videos/animaux_720x404.mp4" autoplay muted controls="controls" playsinline>
     Votre navigateur ne supporte pas les vidéos au format HTML5.<br>
     Veuillez mettre à jour votre navigateur ou utilisez Mozilla Firefox.
  </video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this to toggle the `muted` attribute.

```
$("video").click( function (){
    $(this).prop("muted", !$(this).prop("muted"));
});
```

Also see [this post](http://blog.millermedeiros.com/unsolved-html5-video-issues-on-ios/) for what's possible on iOS or the official [Apple doc on HTMLMediaElement](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkitjs/htmlmediaelement).

Comment: I tried something similar : 
var maVideo = document.getElementById("video");
         maVideo.addEventListener("click", function(){
            maVideo.removeAttribute("muted");
         });
But it doesn't work, like your code :(